# Deploy a PHP web application onto a shared web server and protect my code from being read

Tags: php, deployment

I want to use PHP to build web application for my client(s) but I don't want my code to be read by other(s) when the web is deployed onto a shared web server.

How can I protect my PHP codes?

Comment: use .htaccess to protect your files

Comment: .htaccess wont protect against others on the same server.

Answer (score 4):

1. File system permissions to restrict access.
2. Use [ioncube encoder](http://www.ioncube.com/php_encoder.php) or [zend guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/).